# How to print a web page without opening a popup window?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I want to print a web page using JavaScript. But I do not want to open the page as a popup windows. How can I print directly a web page like 'mypage.aspx' using JavaScript window.print method without opening it as a popup window?

Also the condition is 'I don't want to use any ActiveX for this'

Here is what I want to try:

```
var printWindow, printData; printWindow = window.open("", "printVersion", "menubar,scrollbars,width=640,height=480,top=0,left=0");

printData=document.getElementById("lblReport").innerHTML; printWindow.document.write(printData); 
printWindow.document.close(); 
printWindow.print();
```

Comment: What is the problem with calling window.print in your web page?

Comment: Alsciende,
There is no problem of calling this but before calling this I have to open a window, which I do not want to open. Here is the scenario:

I have a page1.aspx page and now I generated some out put and which is in page2.aspx now how can I print page2.aspx without opening the same?

Comment: Gaurav, calling window.print(), as Rosdi suggested first, will *not* open a popup window. It will open a printoptions dialog, this is not a popup window, neither is it something that you can prevent. This window is necessary so the user can select which printer to print to, paper size, etc.

Comment: Sorry buddies I think there is some ambiguity in my words, here is what I want to try:
[code]
 var printWindow, printData;
    printWindow = window.open("", "printVersion", "menubar,scrollbars,width=640,height=480,top=0,left=0");
    printData=document.getElementById("lblReport").innerHTML;
    printWindow.document.write(printData);
    printWindow.document.close(); 
    printWindow.print();
[/code]

Comment: Gaurav, you can edit your original question, paste it there.

Comment: @Guarav BinaryLV's way is the way to go then.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simpliest solution is to load the content of that mypage.aspx to an iframe then on iframes onload event call the window.print.

```
<button onclick="printPage()">print</button>
<div id="printerDiv" style="display:none"></div>
<script>
   function printPage()
   {
      var div = document.getElementById("printerDiv");
      div.innerHTML = '<iframe src="mypage.aspx" onload="this.contentWindow.print();"></iframe>';
   }
</script>
```

Comment: You helped me solve this problem too, thanks for the code snippet!

Comment: it should work, please see Error Console, maybe there is/are js error(s), please check.

Answer (score 6):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Print</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="all.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
    </head>
<body>
    <p>I get printed</p>
    <form>
        <input type="button" onclick="window.print()" value="Print" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure `all.css` is on top and `print.css` at the bottom, it should work.

Comment: I have done everything, please go through my question and comment first and then suggest some solution.

Comment: Gaurav, you're getting free help from a community of volunteers. Scolding them for answers that you don't like isn't a good way to encourage them to spend their time to help you...

Comment: @Gaurav, I rewrite the answer to include a full working html sample, hope it helps.

Comment: Hey guys, I am really sorry, if you feel my words are harsh, I do not want to push anyone for answer. I am just wandering for solution.

Comment: I think what Gaurav wants is the page to automatically print without user interaction at all?, call window.print() in body onLoad then.

Comment: To clarify the point of the print stylesheet, if you only want to print *part* of the page, put `display: none` rules in your `print.css` so that all other parts of the page are hidden. Then when you call normal `print()`, it will only print the non-hidden element.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it works, but you may try to create invisible `iframe`, load page2.aspx in it and then print it.

Answer (score 1):

Um. Just use `window.print();` directly on the page. By itself it does not open a new window (apart from the print properties window to set printing options).

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a CSS print style sheet and avoid using javascript altogether -all the user has to do them is print the page. e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```