# Firefox won't print iframe styled with display:none

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I'm using code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651559/how-to-print-a-web-page-without-opening-a-popup-window/2651961#2651961) answer to print a separate page directly from a print button. The user clicks the print button and a url is sent to the print function. The print function loads the separate page into a `display:none` iframe and prints that iframe `onLoad`. It works in IE, Chrome but not firefox. In firefox it loads the page into the div but never prints or opens the print dialog. It turns out firefox will not print an iframe if it is set to `display:none` as below:

```
<div id="printerDiv" style="display:none"></div>
```

Is this expected behavior? All other browsers print, I'm thinking of posting on Bugzilla.  I tried some css "tricks" to make the div not display where the user can see it, but it's always visible in some way. I'm currently using the below CSS to make the iframe invisible:

```
#printerDiv iframe{
width:1px !important;
height:1px !important;
border:0 !important;
margin:0 !important;
}
```

But it's margins still exist and leave a 14px gap once the iframe is generated.
Is there some way to make the iframe not be visible *at all* without the `display:none` attribute? Better yet, is there some way to do this without a hack like that?

I even tried using CSS to set the iframe to `display:block` @print media types and `display:none` for screen, the JS function still won't print.

Comment: It may be because the URL is on a different domain.

Comment: It's not, in fact I'm passing a relative link. I tried an absolute link but it gets the same problem.

Comment: Just absolutely position the iframe off the page..

Comment: @Greg Agnew Post that as an answer if you want and I'll accept it, it's the solution I'm using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you absolutely position your iFrame off the page, it will still be printable while not being visible to the user.

```
#printerDiv iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. Only the position/top attributes proved necessary though, as the iframe is no longer visible.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. When the display attribute is set to none, Firefox returns 0 for `$('#printerDiv').css('height')`, `$('#printerDiv')[0].style.height` or when `outerHeight()` or `outerWidth()` are called on the element.

I used z-index for this which does not bind you to use `position:absolute`.

So, you could have this in the css file:

```
#printerDiv { z-index: -10; }
```

Then, when you want to make it visible, just set the z-index using a jquery css() call.

Comment: I'll try this solution as soon as I can as if it works it's preferable to the absolute positioning.

Comment: Yes I know. :) I had to figure this one out just recently. Also, if you use absolute positioning, it might be a little better to use `visibility:hidden` than `display:none` anyways.

Comment: The element takes up considerable so visibility:hidden won't work, and setting width/height doesn't hide it either. This solution works great in Firefox and Chrome. Still not in IE but I think I'll have to do a separate solution for IE altogether.

Comment: BTW, the element needs `position:absolute` in the CSS for `z-index` to work in Firefox, so I included that in your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you control the content of the iframe, make it print itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.print()
</script>
```

Comment: Adding that text to the source document DOES start the print dialog in firefox if the source is opened (which I'm trying to avoid, this is a straight-print job). However it doesn't work in the `display:none` iframe, so my button still doesn't work

Comment: I updated the question, the problem isn't JS it's how Firefox handles styles apparently.

Comment: Make it one pixel by one pixel instead.

Comment: I tried that, the full width of the default frame then shows once it's been opened...